# How to build solutions list in multiple properties file using msbuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I am having following list of Msbuild properties file.

C:\Build\Mainscript\Master.targets

C:\Build\Mainscript\Master.properties

C:\Build\Component1\build.comp1.properties

C:\Build\Component2\build.comp2.properties

```
         .
         .
```

C:\build\Component3\build.compn.properties

Component1.properties has list of solutions like follows

```
<Solution Include="C:\build\Component1\Mysoltuion.sln;">
      <Group>Firstcomp</Group>
      <AdditionalProperties>
        ValidateXaml=false;
        ReferencePath=$(DefaultReference);
      </AdditionalProperties>
      <IsRebuild>False</IsRebuild>
    </Solution>
```

Component2.properties has list of solutions like follows

```
<Solution Include="C:\build\Component2\Mysoltuion.sln;">
      <Group>Firstcomp</Group>
      <AdditionalProperties>
        ValidateXaml=false;
        ReferencePath=$(DefaultReference);
      </AdditionalProperties>
      <IsRebuild>False</IsRebuild>
    </Solution>
```

Master.properties will have common properties for all components.

```
<Components Include="C:\Build\Comp1\Build.comp1.properties">
      <ComponentName>Comp1</ComponentName>
    </Components>

    <Components Include="C:\Build.CompN.Properties">
      <ComponentName>CompN</ComponentName>
    </Components>
```

I am having a target as follows which is helping me to build all components

```
  <Target Name="BuildAll" Inputs="@(Components)" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">

    <MSBuild Projects="@(Components)"

             Targets="BuildComponent" />

  </Target>
```

I want to build some particular components alone most of the time. How to pass particular components alone.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to your similar question here:
[How to pass items one by one to another msbuild task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520424/how-to-pass-items-one-by-one-to-another-msbuild-task)

Basically, you can access custom metadata for each item in an ItemGroup like this:

```
<Target Name="BuildAll" Inputs="@(Components)" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">
    <MSBuild Projects="%(Identity)" 
             Targets="%(ComponentName)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Metadata can be accessed like this. But For my sceanrio this solution did not work